# Error: Module 'sqlite3' has no connect member

Tags: python, pylint

I have written a few python code lines. But I keep on getting the following error: Module 'sqlite3' has no 'connect' member pylint(no-member)[6,8].
Any ideas what might be causing this.

```
import sqlite3
import os
os.chdir('D:/SQL/Databases')

conn = sqlite3.connect('GVP - Eruptions Trial 1.2.db')
```

Comment: this questions applies to this [pyodbc issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/115) as well.

Answer (score 2):

PyLint does not load C extensions by default, as a security measure to prevent arbitrary code execution.

To whitelist just the `sqlite3` C extension, you can include in your project a  `.pylintrc` file with the following content:

```
[MASTER]

# Whitelisting sqlite3 C extension
extension-pkg-allow-list=_sqlite3
```

You can verify that it gets read correctly by running `pylint --generate-rcfile` in your terminal to print the current config loaded by pylint. You should see that the option you added is there:

[image]

This solved it for me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can safely ignore these PyLint warnings.

As a security measure, PyLint does not import untrusted C extensions (*we* may trust SqLite but *PyLint* defines "trusted" as being in the standard library). See [here](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/c_extensions.html) for details (including how to whitelist your extensions if you want to remove the warnings).

The *reason* it does not import it is because that would allow an attacker to run arbitrary code. If it had a way of creating the AST (abstract syntax tree) without importing (i.e., by just examining the file), it would be a lot safer.

It should, however, *run* just fine.

Comment: just to be clear, whitelisting means to import and build the AST, it does not remove the warnings *tout court*, so for me this is the solution