# Data base not showing in python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

so whenever I try to run my code it gives me this error:
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNqjq.png)
this is my code if you guys would like to tell me what is wrong with it it would help and if you guys can fix it would be nice as well because I have been trying to fix it for about 3 weeks now.

Code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('GVP - Eruptions Trial 1.2.db')
DATABASE_FILE = "backpack.db"
"functions"
def show_backpack(connection):
    '''nicely print the backpack info'''
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "Select * FROM contents"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print(f"{'Name':<20}{'Description':<60}")
    for item in results:
        print(f"{item[1]:<20}{item[2]:<60}")


def add_item(connection,item_name,item_description):
    '''add item to backpack database'''
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO contents(name,description) VALUES (?,?)"
    cursor.execute(sql,(item_name,item_description))
    connection.commit()

with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_FILE) as connection :
    show_backpack(connection)
    #add item
    add_item(connection,"fish","me no likey")
    show_backpack()
```

Comment: You can (and should) add your code, not (never?) a picture, even though you are new. It's a simple copy/paste. Select and copy the code from the editor. `edit` the question (there's a link under the question). Paste the code. Then select it again (in the question editor) and click the `{}` button in the format bar. Voilà.

Comment: This `show_backpack()` is missing an argument. And remember, `item` will be indexed to 0 (not 1).

Comment: Also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844593/error-module-sqlite3-has-no-connect-member) has add'l info on the pylint errors.